# How to merge two excel files with columns that have matching variables?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I will explain my problem with following pictures:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

As you can see there is the column 'BvD ID number' that has the same variables (in picture 2 they occur more often).
I would like to merge these two so that I can have picture one with the added information of picture 2.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a [tag:vlookup]?

Comment: I think you could just pivot the second table in rows have BVDid, pub title, pub number. The result should be an "organized" list of ID with related patents.

Answer (score 0):

***Without* Pivot** table, you can use **Subtotal** to get what you want (but not in your desired format, but close enough).

1. Make sure your `ID` is sorted.

[image: Sample data]

2. Select your whole table, including the header.
3. Go to **Data** tab, and click on **Subtotal**

[image: Data tab, then Subtotal]

4. Select `ID` on **At each change in**, use function **Count**, and check `ID` on **Add subtotal to**

[image: Creating subtotal]

5. You can click on <kbd>-</kbd> icon to collapse the detailed info to form a count summary only.

[image: Result] [image: Summary]